# How can I determine the reason for a Python Type Error

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I'm currently using a `try/except` block to treat a particular variable as an iterable when I can, but handle it a different, though correct, manner when it isn't iterable.

My problem is that a TypeException may be thrown for reasons other than trying to iterate with a non-iterable. My check was to use the message attached to the TypeException to ensure that this was the reason and not something like an unsupported operand.

But messages as a part of exceptions have been deprecated. So, how can I check on the reason for my TypeException?

For the sake of completeness, the code I'm using is fairly similar to this:

```
            try:
               deref = [orig[x].value.flatten() for x in y]
            except TypeError as ex:
                if "object is not iterable" in ex.message:
                    x = y
                    deref = [orig[x].value.flatten()]
                else:
                    raise
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using and also the desired outcome..

Comment: why do you need to catch it? Why don't you just check whether it is an iterable first ... like hasattr(y, '\__iter__')

Comment: @SamRedway: Not all iterables have an `__iter__` method.

Comment: @user2357112 huh? Really? I had considered this the definition of an iterable?

Comment: @SamRedway, see the quotation in my answer.. `__iter__` is not the only way a class can iterate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the part that throws the exception you're interested in from the parts that throw unrelated exceptions:

```
try:
    iterator = iter(y)
except TypeError:
    handle_that()
else:
    do_whatever_with([orig[x].value.flatten() for x in iterator])
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way, if it suits your use case, is to use `collections.Iterable`. Because this is such a common task, I tend to wrap it in a function:

```
from collections import Iterable

def iterify(obj):
    return obj if isinstance(obj, Iterable) else [obj]

deref = [orig[x].value.flatten() for x in iterify(y)]
```

But note the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable):

> Checking `isinstance(obj, Iterable)` detects classes that are registered
>   as Iterable or that have an `__iter__()` method, but it does not detect
>   classes that iterate with the `__getitem__()` method. The only reliable
>   way to determine whether an object is iterable is to call `iter(obj)`.